# How to extract only text from HTML in Golang?

Tags: html, go, text

To extract text from HTML, I use a fully [HTML5-compliant tokenizer and parser](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/net/html), like this

```
    s := `
<p>Links:</p><ul><li><a href="foo">Foo</a><li>
<a href="/bar/baz">BarBaz</a></ul><span>TEXT <b>I</b> WANT</span>
<script type='text/javascript'>
/* <![CDATA[ */
var post_notif_widget_ajax_obj = {"ajax_url":"http:\/\/site.com\/wp-admin\/admin-ajax.php","nonce":"9b8270e2ef","processing_msg":"Processing..."};
/* ]]> */
</script>`

    domDocTest := html.NewTokenizer(strings.NewReader(s))
    for tokenType := domDocTest.Next(); tokenType != html.ErrorToken; {
        if tokenType != html.TextToken {
            tokenType = domDocTest.Next()
            continue
        }
        TxtContent := strings.TrimSpace(html.UnescapeString(string(domDocTest.Text())))
        if len(TxtContent) > 0 {
            fmt.Printf("%s\n", TxtContent)
        }
        tokenType = domDocTest.Next()
    }
```

but I got this result

```
Links:
Foo
BarBaz
TEXT
I
WANT
/* <![CDATA[ */
var post_notif_widget_ajax_obj = {"ajax_url":"http:\/\/site.com\/wp-admin\/admin-ajax.php","nonce":"9b8270e2ef","processing_msg":"Processing..."};
/* ]]> */
```

I don't want `CDATA` content. Some idea, how to get only the text content?

Comment: Really what it appears you want here is to ignore anything that's in an unrendered element, aka a `script` tag. To do that you'll need to look not just at `TextToken`s but at `StartTagToken`s. If the token is the start of a script tag ignore the following text tag.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As indicated by @Eric Pauley, I look at `TextTokens` & `StartTagTokens`.
Here is my solution

```golang
    s := `
<p>Links:</p><ul><li><a href="foo">Foo</a><li>
<a href="/bar/baz">BarBaz</a></ul><span>TEXT <b>I</b> WANT</span>
<script type='text/javascript'>
/* <![CDATA[ */
var post_notif_widget_ajax_obj = {"ajax_url":"http:\/\/site.com\/wp-admin\/admin-ajax.php","nonce":"9b8270e2ef","processing_msg":"Processing..."};
/* ]]> */
</script>`

    domDocTest := html.NewTokenizer(strings.NewReader(s))
    previousStartTokenTest := domDocTest.Token()
loopDomTest:
    for {
        tt := domDocTest.Next()
        switch {
        case tt == html.ErrorToken:
            break loopDomTest // End of the document,  done
        case tt == html.StartTagToken:
            previousStartTokenTest = domDocTest.Token()
        case tt == html.TextToken:
            if previousStartTokenTest.Data == "script" {
                continue
            }
            TxtContent := strings.TrimSpace(html.UnescapeString(string(domDocTest.Text())))
            if len(TxtContent) > 0 {
                fmt.Printf("%s\n", TxtContent)
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: How to remove CSS also ?

Comment: Older comment, but figured I'd chime in with the answer since I had to solve it as well. To filter out CSS, you would modify the `if previousStartTokenTest.Data == "script"` line to `if previousStartTokenTest.Data == "script" || previousStartTokenTest.Data == "style"`. All `<style>` elements will then be ignored.

Comment: This code is based upon golang.org/x/net/html (go get golang.org/x/net/html)

Answer (score 5):

If you use [github.com/PuerkitoBio/goquery](https://github.com/PuerkitoBio/goquery) it's pretty easy to achieve what you want.

- You first need to use [document.Find()](http://godoc.org/github.com/PuerkitoBio/goquery#Selection.Find) to identify the element you want to remove, in your case `scripts`, so `document.Find(scripts)`
- Then, you need to remove it from the document using [element.Remove()](http://godoc.org/github.com/PuerkitoBio/goquery#Selection.Remove)
- Finally, you print/get the text using [document.Text()](http://godoc.org/github.com/PuerkitoBio/goquery#Selection.Text)

So, the final code would be

```
package main

import (
  "fmt"
  "strings"
  "github.com/PuerkitoBio/goquery"
)

func main(){
  s := `<p>Links:</p><ul><li><a href="foo">Foo</a><li><a href="/bar/baz">BarBaz</a></ul><span>TEXT <b>I</b> WANT</span><script type='text/javascript'>/* <![CDATA[ */var post_notif_widget_ajax_obj = {"ajax_url":"http:\/\/site.com\/wp-admin\/admin-ajax.php","nonce":"9b8270e2ef","processing_msg":"Processing..."};/* ]]> */</script>`

  p := strings.NewReader(s)
  doc, _ := goquery.NewDocumentFromReader(p)

  doc.Find("script").Each(func(i int, el *goquery.Selection) {
      el.Remove()
  })

  fmt.Println(doc.Text()) // Links:FooBarBazTEXT I WANT

}
```

Comment: How to remove CSS also?